# Jquery accordion prevent menu collaspe after postback

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a menu that is a nested ListView Control that is on my master page. I use the Jquery below to turn this ListView into a accordion. The problem is when I click on the Menu titles it will cause a postback. So the submenu flashes and ones the post back is complete it reloads the page and the menu(closing the Active submenu).

```
 $('.head').each(function () {
            var $content = $(this).closest('li').find('.content');
            $(this).click(function (e) {
               // e.preventDefault();
                $content.not(':animated').slideToggle();
            });
        });
```

Comment: jQuery `event.preventDefault()` in your case the `e`. BTW, what's that : `var $open = $();` ?

Comment: @roXon I originally had that in there. But it would prevent the postback. I want to have my cake and eat it too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well simply put there are few ways you can maintain state during postback. Two easiest are using POST and GET, ie the ViewState or some kind of query string.

**Continued**

I would personally recommend using a hidden field, let's say that you want the 3rd item to open on load, then you would use something like

```
<input id="hidMenuItem" type="hidden" value="3" />
```

Then using jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function {
  var itemIndex = $("#hidMenuItem").val();
  $("li .content:nth-child(" + itemIndex + ")").slideToggle();
});
```

To save the open item before postback do this in the `click` event

```
var itemIndex = $("li .content").index(this);
$("#hidMenuItem").val(itemIndex);
```

It's untested but this is the idea.
Hope that helps

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I assume this answer was downvoted cause it's pretty vague and it's more like a rhetorical prose than a technical advice, can you try to be more clear and improve?